# Retrofit 2 : NO Request Body even there is

Tags: php, android, json, retrofit, retrofit2

Have you ever encountered this problem? I made a Post request with retrofit2 but the request body wont feed to the server. Last time I checked the feed it's empty that is why it can't get through the IF statement.  This are my codes:

```
 Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();

    Retrofit newAccountRetro = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://192.168.1.8/waterdistrict/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();

    RetrofitAPI retroAPI = newAccountRetro.create(RetrofitAPI.class);
```

My Requestbody:

```
    NewFormRequest nfr = new NewFormRequest();
    nfr.setFname(fname);
    nfr.setMname(mname);
    nfr.setLname(lname);
    nfr.setUsern(usern);
    nfr.setPs(ps);
    nfr.setContact(contact);
    nfr.setAdd(add);
    nfr.setEmail(email);

    rs = new Presenter(context);
    //TODO:Fix null response of Retrofit
```

This is how I pass my request body

```
   Call<NewFormResponse> nfResponse = retroAPI.newAccount((NewFormRequest) nfr);
    nfResponse.enqueue(new Callback<NewFormResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<NewFormResponse> call, Response<NewFormResponse> response) {
            Log.d(getClass().toString(), response.code()+"-"+new Gson().toJson(response.body())
                    +"-"+call.request().toString()+" - "+call.request().headers().toString());
            if(response.code() == 200){
                rs.nfResponse(response.body().getCode(), response.body().getMessage());
                rs.switchProgress();
            }
        };

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<NewFormResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            rs.switchProgress();
            Log.d(getClass().toString(), t.toString());

        }
    });
```

ENDPOINT:

```
 @POST("addClients.php")
Call<NewFormResponse> newAccount (@Body NewFormRequest newFormRequest);
```

NewFormResponse:

```
public class NewFormResponse {
@SerializedName("code")
@Expose
private Integer code;
@SerializedName("message")
@Expose
private String message;

public Integer getCode() {
    return code;
}

public void setCode(Integer code) {
    this.code = code;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}
}
```

newFormRequest Class

```
public class NewFormRequest {
private String fname;
private String mname;
private String lname;
private String usern;
private String ps;
private String contact;
private String add;
private String email;

public String getFname() {
    return fname;
}

public void setFname(String fname) {
    this.fname = fname;
}

public String getMname() {
    return mname;
}

public void setMname(String mname) {
    this.mname = mname;
}

public String getLname() {
    return lname;
}

public void setLname(String lname) {
    this.lname = lname;
}

public String getUsern() {
    return usern;
}

public void setUsern(String usern) {
    this.usern = usern;
}

public String getPs() {
    return ps;
}

public void setPs(String ps) {
    this.ps = ps;
}

public String getContact() {
    return contact;
}

public void setContact(String contact) {
    this.contact = contact;
}

public String getAdd() {
    return add;
}

public void setAdd(String add) {
    this.add = add;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
}
```

PHP Code

```
<?php
include "connection.php";

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    $response["code"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "failed to connect with the database";
    echo json_encode($response);
} else{
        if(isset($_POST['fname'], $_POST['mname'], $_POST['lname'], $_POST['usern'], $_POST['ps'], $_POST['contact'], $_POST['add'], $_POST['email'])){
            $fname = $_POST['fname'];
            $mname = $_POST['mname'];
            $lname = $_POST['lname'];
            $contactnum = $_POST['contact'];
            $address = $_POST['add'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $usern = $_POST['usern'];
            $password = $_POST['ps'];
            $approval = 0;

            try{
                $conni = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=wddatabase","root","");
                $conni->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $sql_insert = "INSERT INTO clients (fname, mname, lname,  uname, password, contact_num, address, email, approved) 
                    VALUES ('$fname', '$mname', '$lname', '$usern', '$password', '$contactnum', '$address', '$email', '$approval')";
                $conni->exec($sql_insert);
                $response['code']= 1;
                $response['message']='New Record Created';
                echo json_encode($response);
            }catch(PDOException $e){
                $response['code']= 0;
                $response['message']=$e;
                echo json_encode($response);
            }
        } else{
            $response['code']= 0;
                $response['message']="Error";
                echo json_encode($response);
        }
}

?>
```

//RESULT

```
200-{"code":0,"message":"Error"}-Request{method=POST, url=http://192.168.1.8/waterdistrict/addClients.php, tag=null} -
```

Comment: I'm sorry for my bad english

Comment: I tried to use postman and it successfully feed the request body but when I tried to implement it in android I can't get through the If statement because there is nothing even though I tried to made a request body the same I made in postman.

Answer (score 0):

In php you should set header to json before echo json result:

```
 header('Content-Type: application/json');
 echo $json;
```

Comment: I can do Post in Postman but when I implemented it on Android it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

From [Javadocs](http://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/) for Retrofit for the Body annotation.

> The object will be serialized using the Retrofit instance Converter
>   and the result will be set directly as the request body.

I would say that the Converter is having trouble converting your NewFormRequest class to HTTP

If you put your NewFormRequest class in an OkHttp3 RequestBody, that will allow conversion.

If you're using (or willing to use) JSON as the MediaType for the RequestBody, this should work.

Endpoint:

```
    @POST("addClients.php")
    Call<NewFormResponse> newAccount (@Body RequestBody newFormRequest);
```

and calling code:

```
    JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
    jsonObject.addProperty("myJsonTag", nfr);
    String jsonString = new Gson().toJson(jsonObject);

    RequestBody nfrBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(CONTENT_JSON), jsonString);

    Call<NewFormResponse> nfResponse = retroAPI.newAccount(nfrBody);
    nfResponse.enqueue(new Callback<NewFormResponse>() {...
```